# IIS rewrite virtual folder

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I need to create a URL rewrite rule in IIS for the following:

From:

```
http://hostname/virtual_path_folder/myisapi.dll?a=1&b=1
```

To:

```
http://hostname/myisapi.dll?a=1&b=1
```

Basically, I'd just like to hide the virtual_path folder if possible.

Comment: This is probably possible. What IIs version are you using?

Comment: You need this rule to only apply when `myisapi.dll?a=1&b=1` is requested? Or any url?

Comment: Any URL if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could go with the 2 following rules:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect if virtual_path_folder" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^virtual_path_folder/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="virtual_path_folder/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

The first one, `Redirect if virtual_path_folder`, will redirect every request starting with `virtual_path_folder/`. It will prevent anyone from accessing your content using the sub folder.

The second one rewrites any request (`^.*$`) to the sub folder: `virtual_path_folder/{R:0}`

Comment: @cheesemacfly I have a similar problem to fix. Your solution works great but what if I have a virtual_path_folder_B and virtual_path_folder_C for which the rule must not be applied? I tried to add `<rule name="if_not_virtual_path_folder" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^virtual_path_folder/(.*)$" negate="true" /> <action type="None" />` but it doesn't do the trick!

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic You want to avoid the `Rewrite` if the requested url is `http://yourwebsite.com/virtual_path_folder_C` and show the content of `virtual_path_folder_C` instead?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Yes that's it!

Comment: @MaxS-Betclic To do this, you could change the second rule pattern (`<match url="^.*$" />`) to something like: `<match url="^virtual_path_folder_C" negate="true" />`. It would prevent the rewrite when the url starts with `virtual_path_folder_C`. Would it work for you?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Thanks for your reply. Actually I wrote a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965413/iis-rewrite-module-and-sub-applications), it will be easier than adding stuff to comments!