# IIS Rewrite Module and sub applications

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Here's what I have deployed:

[image: IIS deploy]

`testRedirect` is an empty website. All sub-applications are sub-folders that have been converted in application. All of them are ASP .Net MVC sites.

Here's what I want to setup:

- `Http://localhost/` must show the content of `SiteName1` without
  displaying `Http://localhost/SiteName1/` in the adress bar (it must
  stay `Http://localhost/`)
- `Http://localhost/SiteName1/` must show the content of `SiteName1`
  without displaying `Http://localhost/SiteName1/` in the adress bar
  (it must stay `Http://localhost/`)
- `Http://localhost/SiteName2/` shows the content of `SiteName2` and
  displays `Http://localhost/SiteName2/` in the adress bar (Same behavior for `SiteName3` & `SiteName4` and any other sites....)

In other words, I want my `SiteName1` to act like a ***home*** site

What I've tried so far, is something similar to the answer provided by @cheesemacfly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561619/iis-rewrite-virtual-folder):

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect if SiteName1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^SiteName1/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="SiteName1/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

It works great for Case1 & 2 but not the other ones.

I tried to add rules like this one, but it was not successful...

```
<rule name="if_not_SiteName1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^SiteName1/(.*)$" negate="true" />
   <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Are you using any routing system? Because if not, you may be able to use the `IsFile/IsDirectory` condition (so if the requested path, let's assume `http://localhost/SiteName2/default.aspx` or `http://localhost/SiteName2/`, points to a real file/folder, then you don't trigger the rule). Would it work in your case?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I do use routing, these are ASP .Net MVC sites. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best option would be to trigger the rewrite rule you already have only when the url **doesn't** start with one of your sub-applications.

It would be something like:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Redirect if SiteName1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^SiteName1/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to sub folder">
        <match url="^(SiteName2|SiteName3|SiteName4)/" negate="true" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="SiteName1/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

We keep the redirect when `SiteName1/` is requested (we don't need to change this), but the rewrite rule is triggered only when the requested url doesn't start with `SiteName2/` or `SiteName3/` or `SiteName4/` (that's what `url="^(SiteName2|SiteName3|SiteName4)/"` means and we use `negate="true"` to triggered the rule only when the pattern is **not** matched).

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick! But would it be possible not to have to specify `(SiteName2|SiteName3|SiteName4)` and just create rule based on `SiteName1` only? I'll have to deal with different sets of SiteNames (sometimes just `SiteName2` & `SiteName4`, sometimes `2`, `3` and `5`) depending on the webserver. I want to avoid to write specific rulesets for different webserver farms as the only common thing will always be the `SiteName1` rule. Thanks!

Comment: I see your point, I will try to think of a solution and edit my answer if I find a good one :)

Comment: I can't think of a more simple way than using the negate option. Maybe those sub-applications are following a pattern? Like `SiteName[0-9]` or something the same kind?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It would have been too easy! :-) Anyway, thanks for your help!